# Unable to establish a connection to LLDB (Tizen and Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, device, lldb, tizen

When Im trying to run a basic .NET app from VS into a real device after the installation seems to be completed(a modal with the progress installation is shown) I go the below error in a new modal

> Unable to start debugging. Unable to establish a connection to LLDB.
> The following message was written to stderr: closed. See Output Window
> for details.

And the output debug is:

```
Starting: "D:\Installations\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe"  -s
192.168.15.10:26101 shell 0 vs_lldblaunch
"D:\Installations\tizen-studio\tools\sdb.exe" exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The output build is:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The output Tizen is

```
<<< Start debugging "org.tizen.example.HelloWorld" (secure protocol) >>>
Try to terminate running application: org.tizen.example.HelloWorld
Application is not running: 1 
Launching org.tizen.example.HelloWorld 
'org.tizen.example.HelloWorld' is dependent on 'org.tizen.example.HelloWorld-1.0.0.tpk'. 
...successfully launched 
home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/sdbd-plugin-3.4.0/src/lldb_server_launcher.cpp::main():AttachZone failed
```

My environment:

Tizen

- Tizen Studio: 4.5.1
- Tizen SDK Tools: 2.8.6
- BASELINE_SDK_VERSION=2.0.0
- TIZEN_SDK_VERSION=4.5.1

VS

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019: Version 16.11.10
- In my project the API Version: 4.0

Device

- Real device: SSB-SS08NT2(Samsung TV)
- platform.version = 4.0

If I:

Run a **Web App** from **Tizen Studio** into the **emulator**: **WORKS**

Run a **Web App** from **Tizen Studio** into the **real device**: **WORKS**

Run a **.NET App** from **VS** into the **emulator**: **WORKS**

Run a **.NET App** from **VS** into the **real device**: **LAUNCHES THE ABOVE ERROR**

After trying many solutions for a couple days and a factory reset to the device, reinstall VS and even install VS Code and trying there. Im getting the same error
Does anyone know whats the problem?